# How to return a copy of a list in which odd-length lists have been doubled

Tags: ocaml

I need to return a copy of a list in which odd-length lists have been doubled.

For example my list:

```
oddList [[]; [1];[1;2];[1;2;3];[];[5;4;3;2;1]]
```

Must return:

```
oddList [[]; [1; 1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 3]; []; [5; 4; 3; 2; 1; 5; 4; 3; 2; 1]]
```

I tried this without success:

```
let rec listes_paires l = 
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | x :: r -> 
    if length x mod 2 = 0 then (x :: (listes_paires r))
    else ((x@x):: (listes_paires r));;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "trying without success"? Your function is correct?

Comment: Style note: operator precedence and syntax rules mean that _many_ of the parentheses being used here are unnecessary noise.

Comment: I think you mean : for example `liste_paires [[]; [1];[1;2];[1;2;3];[];[5;4;3;2;1]]` returns `[[]; [1; 1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 3]; []; [5; 4; 3; 2; 1; 5; 4; 3; 2; 1]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `List.length` instead of `length`:

```
let rec listes_paires l = match l with
    | [] -> []
    | x :: r -> if List.length x mod 2 = 0 then (x :: (listes_paires r))
    else ((x@x):: (listes_paires r))
```

(Note: your code names the function `listes_paires`, and the question `oddList`.)

You can also type:

```
let listes_paires l = List.map
 (fun x -> if List.length x mod 2 = 0 
           then x else x@x) l
```

Comment: `length` will work if `List` has been opened.